# Js/Jquery Drop event takes .lnk file instead of real file

Tags: javascript, jquery, drag-and-drop

I am trying to add a div link where users can drag and drop files. It works well on every files, but when I drop a Linked (.lnk) file, it takes the lnk file instead of the real one behind the link.

my code

```
$("html").on("drop", "#mydiv", function(event) {
    ...
    data.append("file-0", event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files[0]);
    //then sending data object via ajax
    ...
});
```

is there a way to get the real file on drop ?

Thanks by advance

Comment: I doubt this is possible - even if you parsed the path from the bytes of the `.lnk` file you wouldn't be able to use it; the user has to upload the file themselves.

Comment: Hello, thanks for your response. I think you're right, I ended up displaying a warning about dropping a .lnk file